# ResourceDependency annotation doesn't work in a UIComponent and generates "RES_NOT_FOUND" error in the src

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, annotations

I'm developing a UIComponent that uses a javascript file with @ResourceDependency annotation, but instead of generating a link to the file, it just prints "RES_NOT_FOUND" in the src atribute, like this:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="RES_NOT_FOUND"></script>`

Follow the java code:

```
@ResourceDependency(name="file.js")
public class ComponenteTest extends UIComponentBase {
```

Does anybody know what's happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This particular annotation configuration expects the file to be located in `/resources/file.js` of the public webcontent.

It's exactly the same as if you would be using the following in the view:

```html
<h:outputScript name="file.js" />
```

If the file is located elsewhere, or when the `name` (or `library`) is actually wrong, then it will generate exactly this `RES_NOT_FOUND` URL.